# Norm topology vs metric topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I have been studying functional analysis and the notion of a Frechet metric frequently comes up. 
Not every Frechet metric induces a norm topology, and it is said that this results in a more complicated topological structure than if it arose from a norm.

What are the main advantages of a norm topology when compared to a metric-only topology?

**EDIT**

After some more thinking it seems that the main advantage of a norm-induced topology over a purely metric-induced one is that the topology induced by a norm is because of translation invariance and homogeneity completely determined by its topology at 0, which greatly simplifies thinking about normed vector spaces.

Comment: Probably part of the answer can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922567/difference-between-the-algebraic-and-topological-dual-of-a-topological-vector-sp/1922599#1922599 In general as an application, many topologies of some functional spaces are induced by seminorm, this often serves in distribution theory.